# Refactor large controller method into model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I have a rails app ported from php codebase.
I have a long controller method that basically calculate a total price based on the items in my cart. This is a legacy method that is directly ported from the php code.

```rb
def total
    order = @cart.get_or_create_order
    order_contents = order_contents_for(order)

    discounts = {
      events: {},
      subjects: {},
      products: {}
    }

    adjusted_pricing = {}
    free = false
    shipping = 0
    total = 0

    # Logic for computing shipping price

    # Construct discount hash

    order_contents.each do |item|
       if (item.variant_price.present?)
         price = item.variant_price
       end
       else
         price = item.price
       end

       price_adjustments = {}
       popped_from = []

       # it's the issue due to legacy database structure,
       # product_id, subject_id and event_id is each column in
       # the database
       if (discounts[:products][item.product_id])
          price_adjustments = discounts[:products][item.product_id]
          discounts[:products].delete(item.product_id)
          popped_from = [:products, item.product_id]
       elsif (discounts[:subjects][item.subject_id])
          price_adjustments = discounts[:subjects][item.subject_id]
          discounts[:subjects].delete(item.subject_id)
          popped_from = [:subjects, item.subject_id]
       elsif (discounts[:events][item.event_id])
          price_adjustments = discounts[:events][item.event_id]
          discounts[:events].delete(item.event_id)
          popped_from = [:events, item.event_id]
       end

       if (adjustment = price_adjustments['$'])
          adjusted_price = price + adjustment
       elsif (adjustment = price_adjustments['%'])
          adjusted_price = price + price * (adjustment / 100.0)
          discounts[popped_from[0]][popped_from[1]] = price_adjustments
       else
          adjusted_price = price
       end

       adjusted_pricing[item.product_id] = {price: adjusted_price, discount: price - adjusted_price}

       total += adjusted_price
    end

    total += shipping
end
```

Above code is a huge pieces of code for a method, so I'm trying to refactor it and move it to a model `price_calculator`.

```rb
def calculate_total_for(order)
  order_contents = order.current_order_contents
  product_adjustments = order.product_adjustments

  shipping = calculate_shipping_price(order_contents, product_adjustments)

  discounts = construct_discount_hash(product_adjustments)

  adjusted_pricing = construct_adjusted_price_hash(discounts, order_contents)

  total_price = adjusted_pricing.inject(0) { |total, (k, v)| total + v[:price] }

  {
    total_price: total_price + shipping,
    shipping: shipping,
    adjusted_pricing: adjusted_pricing
  }
end
```

What I did basically, still in the process of move the previous huge method into its own class and split the logic into a separate private method in that class such as `calculate_shipping_price`, `construct_discount_hash`.

I know it's far from a good code. Break it into private method ooks good in term of readability, but I start to feel it's getting hard to make a test for it. Hopefully, someone here can give an advice or a guideline, what's the best way to refactor above code in ruby.

PS: I'm new to ruby/rails, I previously code mostly in C#/Javascript, so there are some idiom or ruby-way to doing things that I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example you mentioned, I would use [Extract Class from Method](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html) refactoring and use a [Service Object](http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/04/30/gourmet-service-objects.html) instead of moving everything in a model.

Here is an overview of how to do it, of course I leave the implementation for you:

```
class Test
  def total
    order = @cart.get_or_create_order
    order_contents = order_contents_for(order)

    discounts = {
      events: {},
      subjects: {},
      products: {}
    }

    service = CalculateTotal.new(order, order_contents, discounts)

    if service.success?
      # Success logic
    else
      flash[:error] = service.error
      # Failure logic
    end
  end
end

class CalculateTotal
  attr_reader :success, :error

  def initialize(order, order_contents, discounts)
    @order = order
    @order_contents = order_contents
    @discounts = discounts
  end

  def call
    sum_orders + adjusted_prices + shipping
  end

  def success?
    !@error
  end

  private

  def sum_orders
    # Logic

    if something_fails
      @error = 'There was an error calculating the price'
    end

    # Logic
  end

  def adjusted_prices
    # Logic
  end

  def shipping
    # Logic
  end
end
```

Comment: While I did not review the implementation. I agree that this is a perfect example of the need for a service object as it is neither a concern of the model nor the controller.

Comment: Awesome answer. I got the idea, I'll try to implement this.